# JSDoc документация с rest parameters

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

У меня есть некий класс `A` и `B` имеющий вид:

```js
class A {
  constructor () {
    this.otherClass = new B()
    this.id = 1
  }

  methodName (...args) {
    return this.otherClass.otherClassMethod(this.id, ...args)
  }
}

class B {
  /**
   * @param {number} userId Unique identifier of the target user
   * @param {number} data Data object
   * @return {Promise<boolean>}
   */
  otherClassMethod (userId, data) {
    // do magic
  }
}
```

Класс `А` содержит алиасы на методы класса `B`, но заполняет часть из аргументов сам, а остальное берет из своих аргументов используя [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters)

Как я могу задокументировать остаточные параметры (Rest parameters) используя JSDoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данный момент я не нашел ни одного нормального решения сделать это и просто продублировал все аргументы вместо rest parameters